# What to do with buffer in C

Tags: c

I am trying to use a function that returns `char * buffer` to trap random user input from standard input and return a `char*` (that is, a string) with the input until `'\n'` or `'\0'` is detected as input.

However, the function `user_input()` crashed at the second occurence of `c = getchar();`  near the end of the function (at the **`//Error Here`** comment).

What am I doing wrong?

```
char* user_input(){

    char *buffer=NULL;
    size_t num_read = 0;
    size_t buffer_size = 100;
    char c = '\0';
    char *new_buffer=NULL;
    buffer = malloc(buffer_size);
    fflush(stdin);
    c = getchar();

    while ( c != '\n' || c !='\0' ) {

           if (num_read >= buffer_size) {
           new_buffer=NULL;
           buffer_size *= 2; // try a buffer that's twice as big as before
           new_buffer = realloc(buffer, buffer_size);
           if (new_buffer == NULL) {
                free(buffer);
                return NULL;
                /* Abort - out of memory */
            }
            buffer = new_buffer;
        }
        buffer[num_read] = c;
        num_read++;
        c = getchar();  //Error Here
    }//while
    buffer[num_read] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is OP being down voted so vigorously?  It seems reasonably clear what they are asking.

Comment: You can't `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: Doesn't answer directly you question but replace `if` to `num_read > buffer_size` and `getchar()` doesn't returns `\0` on error but `-1 (EOF)` instead of. Hold in an `int` the `getchar()` return value. Also, why are you setting `\0` as initial value to `c`? don't need to...

Comment: Not sure why there are so many down votes, seems a little like piling on.  The question has merit, and any ambiguity can be cleared up with a little effort.  The asker has obviously done a little work.

Comment: I down voted because IMHO this question is not useful. It's simply "why doesn't my code work". As it stands, for example the title is unexpressive, it won't be helpful to future visitors

Comment: @Flow - you did so in error, as "too localized" is no longer one of the choices for closing a question.  The two close votes recorded claim the question is off topic, however if one follows the link to what as defined to be on topic, the question clearly is.

Comment: I never said that I voted to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ( c != '\n' || c !='\0' ) {
```

should use && instead of || or the loop will never exit

```
while ( c != '\n' && c !='\0' ) {
```

I built it and it worked although there are other bugs in the code such as the "buffer[num_read] = '\0';" at the end could overflow the buffer if there are exactly buffer_size items in the array.

Comment: Should probably also check for `c != EOF`

Comment: Using ( c != '\n' && c !='\0' ), I believe you could only trap 1 entry before leaving, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the issues that I found:

- You cannot call `fflush()` on `stdin`. It leads to undefined behavior. `fflush()` is only for output streams.
- The type for `c` should be an `int`. The `getchar()` will return `EOF` when there is no more input, and `EOF` is a value not equal to any valid value for `unsigned char`. That is why `getchar()` returns an `int`, so your variable receiving the return value of `getchar()` should match that type.
- The sense of the `while` check is incorrect. You will only leave the loop if `c` equals both `\n` and `\0` at the same time, which is not possible. Thus the loop will never exit. If you actually ended the input given to your program, you probably entered an infinite loop, continually allocating until your system ran out of memory. So, you want to leave the loop if `c` equals `\n` or `\0`.
- You should add a check to leave the loop if `c` is `EOF`.
- You should make sure `num_read` is less than `buffer_size` before you assign the `\0` character. This can be done by moving your `realloc()` code to be at the bottom of the `while` loop instead of at the top.

With these changes, the code looks like:

```
char *user_input() {
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t num_read = 0;
    size_t buffer_size = 100;
    int c = '\0';
    char *new_buffer = NULL;
    buffer = malloc(buffer_size);
    c = getchar();
    while (!(c == EOF || c == '\n' || c == '\0')) {
        assert(num_read < buffer_size);
        buffer[num_read++] = c;
        if (num_read >= buffer_size) {
            buffer_size *= 2;   // try a buffer that's twice as big as before
            new_buffer = realloc(buffer, buffer_size);
            if (new_buffer == NULL) {
                free(buffer);
                return NULL;
            }
            buffer = new_buffer;
        }
        c = getchar();
    }                           //while
    assert(num_read < buffer_size);
    buffer[num_read] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Correction: `EOF` is a value not equal to any valid value for `unsigned char`. The `getchar()` function returns either an integer value that will fit into an `unsigned char`, or it returns `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code below.  Try to run it as is, using the 'q' character at first, then you can experiment with other exit criteria later.  By the way, your code worked without modification and did not crash for me (unless buffer overrun occured, but it would never leave the while loop otherwise (as Brian Walker pointed out).  In any case, Try this in any ANSI C compiler: (just don't enter more than 1000 entries :)

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
char* user_input(void);

int main(void)
{
    char *buf;

    buf = malloc(1000);
    //SearchDirectory("C:\\dev");
    sprintf(buf, "%s", user_input());
    printf("%s", buf);

    free(buf);
    return 0;   
}


char* user_input(void){

    char *buffer=NULL;
    size_t num_read = 0;
    size_t buffer_size = 100;
    char c = '\0';
    char *new_buffer=NULL;
    buffer = malloc(buffer_size);
    fflush(stdin);
    c = getchar();

    while ( c != 'q' ) {

           if (num_read >= buffer_size) {
           new_buffer=NULL;
           buffer_size *= 2; // try a buffer that's twice as big as before
           new_buffer = realloc(buffer, buffer_size);
           if (new_buffer == NULL) {
                free(buffer);
                return NULL;
                /* Abort - out of memory */
            }
            buffer = new_buffer;
        }
        buffer[num_read] = c;
        num_read++;
        c = getchar();
    }//while
    buffer[num_read] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}
```